# elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client dependency is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, client

it's my first question.
I have to using ES rest high level client.
my ES server is 6.8.x, so i write my build.gradle file.

```
compile "org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.8.5"
```

but my project dependency works like below.

- Gradle: org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.6.2
- Gradle: org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.8.5
- Gradle: org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.6.2
  .. and more ...

why the wrong version 7.6.2 imported?

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer myself.

the spring boot 2.3.x are using Elasticsearch 7.6.2 by  dependency management(BOM).
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions

the answer is overriding the version in gradle.

```
ext['elasticsearch.version'] = '6.8.5'
```

be careful... this is not working.

```
ext {
        elasticsearch.version = '6.8.5'
}
```

good!

Comment: I confirmed that this solution works. I was stuck because of this for hours!